# Aurora failover leaves connections open as read-only state

Tags: mariadb, c3p0, amazon-aurora

We are using MySQL in Aurora cluster
We have 2 instances - master and slave.
We are working with spring transactions on top of a c3po connection pool.
We are using mariadb jdbc driver (version 2.2.3).

Our url looks like this -
jdbc:mysql:aurora:myclaster-cluster.cluster-xxxxxx.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com:3306/db?rewriteBatchedStatements=true

When testing failover; every few failovers we get into a state of using a read only connection -

```
Caused by: org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException: PreparedStatementCallback; uncategorized SQLException for SQL [INSERT INTO a (a1, a2, a3, a4) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?) on duplicate key update ]; SQL state [HY000]; error code [1290]; (conn=7) The MySQL server is running with the --read-only option so it cannot execute this statement; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: (conn=7) The MySQL server is running with the --read-only option so it cannot execute this statement
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:84)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:81)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:81)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:645)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:866)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:927)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:937)
    at com.persistence.impl.MyDao.insert(MyDao.java:52)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.QuartzJobBean.execute(QuartzJobBean.java:75)
    at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:213)
    ... 1 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: (conn=7) The MySQL server is running with the --read-only option so it cannot execute this statement
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.exceptions.ExceptionMapper.get(ExceptionMapper.java:198)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.exceptions.ExceptionMapper.getException(ExceptionMapper.java:110)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.MariaDbStatement.executeExceptionEpilogue(MariaDbStatement.java:228)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.MariaDbPreparedStatementClient.executeInternal(MariaDbPreparedStatementClient.java:216)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.MariaDbPreparedStatementClient.execute(MariaDbPreparedStatementClient.java:150)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.MariaDbPreparedStatementClient.executeUpdate(MariaDbPreparedStatementClient.java:183)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(NewProxyPreparedStatement.java:410)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$2.doInPreparedStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:873)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$2.doInPreparedStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:866)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:629)
    ... 9 common frames omitted
```

How can we force the driver to return connections **only** to the master instance? Is there a way to force aurora to close all open connection upon failover?

Thanks

Comment: could you indicate how you test failover ? using aws "failover" function ?

Comment: yes, by clicking failover in the AWS Dashboard

Comment: Adding some useful links by AWS - 
1. https://d1.awsstatic.com/whitepapers/RDS/amazon-aurora-connection-management-handbook.pdf
2. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/rds-proxy.html#rds-proxy-connection-pooling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We solved the problem by implementing an ExceptionInterceptor, in which we closed the connection, forcing the pool to create a new one.

This workround  is relevant for mysql-connector-java 5.1.47

```
@Override
public SQLException interceptException(SQLException sqlEx, Connection conn) {
    if (sqlEx.getErrorCode() == READ_ONLY_ERROR_CODE) {
        log.warn("Got read only exception closing the connection {} ", sqlEx.getMessage());
        closeConnection(conn);
    }
    return sqlEx;
}
```

Comment: considering that it remains an open issue on github and your workaround is not detailed there; do you have more details? which exception to catch, where, and how to retry with the pool's new connection? see https://github.com/awspring/spring-cloud-aws/issues/50

Comment: @dlamblin add more details

Comment: Well… I meant that the issue of not handling failover and going to a readonly endpoint is still open in spring-cloud-aws so commenting there would be nice.

I'm not sure what class you're overriding in; I see `ExceptionInterceptor`s implemented as `@ControllerAdvice` like ```@ControllerAdvice
public class ExceptionInterceptor extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

  @ExceptionHandler(CustomException.class)
  public final ResponseEntity<Object> handleAllExceptions(CustomException ex) {
```

And you `closeConnection(conn)`
But where is the logic that reopens it and retries?